# How to send file more than 2MB in multipart Java

Tags: java, multipartform-data

I'm trying to get the files more than 2mb here but not able to receive the same but receiving files less than 2mb with the same method .

```
    javax.servlet.http.Part part = aRequest.getPart("file");
    InputStream stream = part.getInputStream();

    File file = FileUtil.createTempFile();
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
    IOUtils.copy(stream, outputStream);
```

This file is made in temp tomcat folder

Comment: Read the file in batches. So read in 1,000 lines at a time and write 1,000 lines at a time.

Comment: You're asking about how to send but you posted the receiving code. And if you already know it fails above 2Mb why are you asking how to send it? @JordanGS Why? and who said the file contains lines?

Comment: Do you get any kind of error? Did you configure an upload limit in Tomcat?

Comment: Seems like some limitation placed by the servlet container.

Comment: For example, if you are using tomcat, there's a 2MB default limit on the POST data. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: @EJP I made an assumption, read it 1,000 bytes at a time. See [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077304/how-do-i-read-file-x-bytes-at-a-time-in-java)

Comment: @JordanGS I didn't ask how, I asked why, and you still haven't answered. You haven't stated *why* reading 1000 lines or bytes at a time is going to change anything. Showing me an example doesn't answer that question.